# read and write to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am doing a PHP/mySQL program for my first time and could need some advice.

The program I want to create will work as follows... It will be an form that you send to a server if something is wrong. You want to be able to fill in a form yourself. The problem will then show on an other computor.

I guess i need to write to a mySQL database and then read it from the next computor after I've connected them to my database. But how do I do this in the best way?

I've succeeded to download XAMPP and make a table in mySQL. Also fields where i put information in and a submit button.

I get errors at:

```
$operationstep = $_POST['Operation step'];
$problem_detail = $_POST['Problem detail'];
```

> Notice: Undefined index: Operation step in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\avvikelse.php on line 21
>
> Notice: Undefined index:
>   Problem detail in E:\xampp\htdocs\avvikelse.php on line 22
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: operation_step in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\avvikelse.php on line 25 Error: You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'step, Problem detail)
>   VALUES ('', '',' at line 1

```
// blabla, connetcting...

$operationstep = $_POST['Operation step'];
$problem_detail = $_POST['Problem detail'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO avvikelsekort (Operation step, Problem detail) VALUES
('$operation_step', '$problem_detail')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
        die('Error: ' .mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

I now did as you said Marco and i get Array(0) {} My form looks like this

```
    <form action="avvikelse.php" method="POST" />
    <p>Operation step: <input type="text" name"Operation step" /></p>
    <p>Problem detail: <input type="text" name"Problem detail" /></p>    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: add `var_dump($_POST);` just before `$operationstep = $_POST['Operation step'];` to inspect your incoming `POST` data.

Comment: I updated my question now after I did what u told me. Why is my POST empty?

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

If you use spaces in your field names you must use backticks.
More, if you call variables

```
$operationstep = $_POST['Operation step'];
$problem_detail = $_POST['Problem detail'];
```

your query should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO avvikelsekort (`Operation step`, `Problem detail`) VALUES
    ('$operationstep', '$problem_detail')";
```

And, last but not least, remember you **MUST always sanitize user input** to avoid sql injection!

**EDITED**:
Your form is wrong. Try this:

```
<form action="avvikelse.php" method="POST" />
    <p>Operation step: <input type="text" name="Operation step" /></p>
    <p>Problem detail: <input type="text" name="Problem detail" /></p>    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: +1, but not only that - allso reading the POST parameters, spaces are converted to %20

Answer (score 1):

You can't have spaces in your Post/Get names:

```
$operationstep = $_POST['Operation step'];
$problem_detail = $_POST['Problem detail'];
```

Try

```
$operationstep = $_POST['Operation_step'];
$problem_detail = $_POST['Problem_detail'];
```

or rename them in the form.

Also:

```
$operationstep = $_POST['Operation step'];
$problem_detail = $_POST['Problem detail'];
```

Does not match the inserts you are doing - note the variable names you used on the insert and how the column names with spaces should be referred to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO avvikelsekort (`Operation step`, `Problem detail`) VALUES
('$operation_step', '$problem_detail')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting notice Undefined index because that index doesn't exist in `$_POST` variable. Don't use spaces in index. Edit your form and use underscores in name attribute of your input fields and you use `$operation_step` in query, while `$operationstep` while assignment. And use backticks for table name in query.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have answered, you are getting an Undefined index message due to the fact the value does not exist in the `$_POST` array.

I suggest that you sanitize your data before putting `$_POST` data into variables since any post data might contain some form of malicious data which can lead to SQL injection attacks. You can check out other secure development practices at: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Guide_Project